# If momentum is the generator of translations in position space, does position act similarly in momentum space?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, momentum, group-theory

Since $\exp(-ia\hat{p})|x\rangle=|x+a\rangle$, do we find that $\exp(-ik\hat{x})|p\rangle=|p+k\rangle$? If so, I don't think I've seen this symmetry explicitly discussed yet, how do we interpret it? It looks like a translation in momentum space...

The question in context stems from my being able to write
$$\exp(-iL_z\phi)|x,y\rangle=T_x(-y\phi)T_y(x\phi)|x,y\rangle = |x-y\phi,y+x\phi\rangle = R(\phi)|x,y\rangle$$
for infinitesimal rotation angle $\phi$. I'd like to write a similar statement to show
$$\exp(-iL_z\phi)|p_x,p_y\rangle= R(\phi)|p_x,p_y\rangle$$

Comment: You cannot factor as you suggest because $xp_y$ and $yp_x$ do not commute.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Hm.. I thought $$\exp(-iL_z\phi)=1-iL_z\phi+\dots \approx (1-ixp_y\phi+\dots)(1+iyp_x\phi-\dots) = \exp(-ixp_y\phi)\exp(-iyp_x\phi)$$
ought to work since I'm considering infinitesimal $\phi$.

Comment: Only to first order in $\phi$.   You cannot compose a finite rotation this way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true that $\hat{x}$ generates translations in momentum space.
We know that $\hat{p}$ is represented by $-i 
\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ in position space. This follows because $\hat{x} \mapsto x$ and $\hat{p} \mapsto -i 
\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ are a representation of the algebra $[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar$ on the space of wave functions. Namely, given a wave function $\psi(x)$ we have
\begin{align}
x \left( -i 
\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right) \psi(x) - \left( -i 
\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right) x \,\psi(x) = i \hbar \psi(x) \,.
\end{align}
This tells us that $\hat{p}$ generates translations in position space, because if we make a small translation and Taylor-expand, we find that the linear operator (the generator) is the derivative.

Similarly, $\hat{x} \mapsto i 
\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial p}$ and $\hat{p} \mapsto p$ are a representation of the algebra on wave functions $\psi(p)$ in momentum space. By the same token, this implies that $\hat{x}$ generates translations in momentum space.